# Java How to return back after using methods

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Is it possible to use a while loop to constantly make my code loop until the user chooses a prompt that ends the code? Here's my code if you want to see the context. The code itself isn't really that important I just want to know if i can add a while loop in my method to allow the user to always loop back to the printMenu() after calling a method.

```
  import java.io.*;
  public class Plane {
   /*Plane's seats will resemble
    * | [A1] [B1] [C1] [D1] [E1] |
    * | [A2] [B2] [C2] [D2] [E2] |
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
     BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(inStream);

     printMenu();
     try {
      String choiceString = bufRead.readLine();
      int choiceInt = Integer.parseInt(choiceString);
      if (choiceInt == 1) {
       makeSeatReservation();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 2) {
       try {
        Cancel();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

      if (choiceInt == 3) {
       printSeating();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 4) {
       cancelFlights();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 5) {
       FlightTakeoff();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 6) {
       System.out.println("Program will terminate");
       System.exit(0);
      } else {
       System.out.println("Invalid Number");
      }
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
    /**
     * Menu
     */

   public static void printMenu() {
     System.out.println(" Booking Menu ");
     System.out.println("                ");
     System.out.println("Please press the corresponding numbers to perform a specific action");
     System.out.println("1. Make a reservation");
     System.out.println("2. Cancel a reserved seat");
     System.out.println("3. View the current available/reserved seats 
      remaining ");
      System.out.println("4. Cancel the flight"); System.out.println("5. Flight takeoff"); System.out.println("6. Quit"); //This will end my code
     }
```

Comment: You need to format your code properly. This is very hard to read.

Comment: And yes, that's entirely possible. Show what you've tried so we know what you're aiming for.

Comment: ok ill edit the question

Comment: The normal thing to do is use a `do { statements } while( condition );` when you want to present a prompt at least once, and continue until a user explicitly exits.

Answer (score 1):

I think kobiF solution is good enough. I only want to add a few changes that make better the approach. But it's just my "style". 
I try to change the if's to a switch and do the same while or maybe better put it in a do..while loop because you want to do it unless one time

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
boolean exit = false;   
while (!exit) {
    printMenu();
     try {
      String choiceString = bufRead.readLine();
      int choiceInt = Integer.parseInt(choiceString);
      if (choiceInt == 1) {
       makeSeatReservation();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 2) {
       try {
        Cancel();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

      if (choiceInt == 3) {
       printSeating();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 4) {
       cancelFlights();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 5) {
       FlightTakeoff();
      }

      if (choiceInt == 6) {
       System.out.println("Program will terminate");
       System.exit(0);
      } else {
       System.out.println("Invalid Number");
      }
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```

I added a variable called "exit" and put a while loop around your code. All you have to do is put something like: exit = true; wherever you want the user to be able to exit the loop. Is this what you were asking for? Let me know.